# how to merge two array of object in following format using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
array1 = [{
    questionId: "5e52b55330bb2cee102b9a39",
    note: "Name",
    prefillValue: "prasanna"
},

{
    questionId: "5e52b56b30bb2cee102b9a3f",
    note: "Mobile Number",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b58230bb2cee102b9a42",
    note: "Agent Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
    note: "Location",
    prefillValue: null
}
]


array2 = [{
    questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: "skk@gmail.com"
},
{
    questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: "34"
},
{
    questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
    note: "Location",
    prefillValue: "Chennai"
}
]
```

**Expected output:**

```
array3 = [{
        questionId: "5e52b55330bb2cee102b9a39",
        note: "Name",
        prefillValue: "prasanna"
    },

    {
        questionId: "5e52b56b30bb2cee102b9a3f",
        note: "Mobile Number",
        prefillValue: null
    }, {
        questionId: "5e52b58230bb2cee102b9a42",
        note: "Agent Email",
        prefillValue: null
    }, {
        questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
        note: "Email",
        prefillValue: null
    }, {
        questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
        note: "Email",
        prefillValue: "skk@gmail.com"
    }, {
        questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
        note: "Agent ID",
        prefillValue: "34"
    },
    {
        questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
        note: "Location",
        prefillValue: "Chennai"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to merge arrays without ending up with duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to copy properties from one object to another

```js
const array1 = [{
      questionId: "5e52b55330bb2cee102b9a39",
      note: "Name",
      prefillValue: "prasanna"
  },

  {
      questionId: "5e52b56b30bb2cee102b9a3f",
      note: "Mobile Number",
      prefillValue: null
  },
  {
      questionId: "5e52b58230bb2cee102b9a42",
      note: "Agent Email",
      prefillValue: null
  },
  {
      questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
      note: "Email",
      prefillValue: null
  },
  {
      questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
      note: "Agent ID",
      prefillValue: null
  },
  {
      questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
      note: "Location",
      prefillValue: null
  }
]


const array2 = [{
      questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
      note: "Email",
      prefillValue: "skk@gmail.com"
  },
  {
      questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
      note: "Agent ID",
      prefillValue: "34"
  },
  {
      questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
      note: "Location",
      prefillValue: "Chennai"
  }
]


const array3 = array1.map(o => Object.assign(o, array2.find(a => a.questionId === o.questionId)));

console.log(array3)
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let array1 = [{
    questionId: "5e52b55330bb2cee102b9a39",
    note: "Name",
    prefillValue: "prasanna"
},

{
    questionId: "5e52b56b30bb2cee102b9a3f",
    note: "Mobile Number",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b58230bb2cee102b9a42",
    note: "Agent Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
    note: "Location",
    prefillValue: null
}
]


let array2 = [{
    questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: "skk@gmail.com"
},
{
    questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: "34"
},
{
    questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
    note: "Location",
    prefillValue: "Chennai"
}
]

let array3 = [...array1,...array2];

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: This is not an array of objects as the OP described.

Comment: it should work with the object provided in the question,

Comment: I need to remove duplicated QuestionID from the first array

Comment: Then you should filter them before merging

Comment: Please give me one example

Comment: So you wanna remove duplicate `QuestionID` Objects in both array or only first one

Comment: @Prasannawatson take a look at  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56768137/9871756)

Comment: @Badasskid only first one

Answer (score 0):

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

You can remove duplicate keys in this way.

```
let array1 = [{
    questionId: "5e52b55330bb2cee102b9a39",
    note: "Name",
    prefillValue: "prasanna"
},

{
    questionId: "5e52b56b30bb2cee102b9a3f",
    note: "Mobile Number",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b58230bb2cee102b9a42",
    note: "Agent Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
    note: "Location",
    prefillValue: null
}
]

var uniq = {}
var arrFiltered = arrays1.filter(obj => !uniq[obj.questionId] && (uniq[obj.questionId] = true));
console.log('Filtered Array:', arrFiltered)
```

reference can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = [{
    questionId: "5e52b55330bb2cee102b9a39",
    note: "Name",
    prefillValue: "prasanna"
},

{
    questionId: "5e52b56b30bb2cee102b9a3f",
    note: "Mobile Number",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b58230bb2cee102b9a42",
    note: "Agent Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: null
},
{
    questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
    note: "Location",
    prefillValue: null
}
]


let array2 = [{
    questionId: "5e52b55e30bb2cee102b9a3c",
    note: "Email",
    prefillValue: "skk@gmail.com"
},
{
    questionId: "5e52c39730bb2cee102b9a47",
    note: "Agent ID",
    prefillValue: "34"
},
{
    questionId: "5e54dbdd30bb2c6018f488ca",
    note: "Location",
    prefillValue: "Chennai"
}
]


let array3 = array1.concat(...array2);

console.log(array3)
```